# Cloud Endpoints intermittent 404

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

We started getting some intermittent 404 responses from our cloud endpoints backend 2 days from now. Sometimes happen, sometimes not. Usually when there is a lot of calls from the same client id in a short period of time. Is something happening? Any kind of quota or something like that is in place now?

Thanks

Comment: The problem still persists... If I go from APIs Explorer and make a simple request many times, each 3, 4 times I get a 404 and the request doesn't even reach the server. Any update about that?

Comment: When I change de default version to an older one, and change back to the current, without modifying any code, the problem disappears. Even newer deployed versions, when starting getting 404, I need to do the same process, back with default to previous one and set default to latest version again.